# Wordpress WooCommerce Customer List not populating

Tags: wordpress, report, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce with my Wordpress site. When logged in to my wordpress admin area, I go to WooCommerce > Reports > Customers tab > then I click on Customer List.

This list should be populated with Name, Username, Email, Location, Orders, Spent, Last order, and Actions. However, nothing is showing up even though I have done test orders as a logged in user and as a guest. Can anyone help as to why the Customer List is not properly populating?

Answer (score 1):

If a user completes a transaction as a guest, the information will not be saved in the Customer List. When a user signs up for an account, they get saved as a customer, and this is where the information on Customer List comes from.

Also were you logged in as a customer or an admin / manager? Its possible that if you were not logged in as a customer the info would not be displayed.